# Extracting value from json string C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

My json string is as follows:

```
{
  "data": {
    "order_reference": "7000016543", 
    "package_data": [
      {
        "tracking_no": "34144582723408", 
        "package_reference": "7000016543"
      }
    ]
  }, 
  "success": true
}
```

How do I get ***tracking_no*** from this json.

I tried using

```
dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(bytesAsString);
```

and then

```
foreach (var obj in jsonObj.items)
        {

        }
```

but it only yields order reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem about your code is: there is no collection on your root json object. I mean it is not an object. Since it is just an object and it's child you can access is directly. And then you have a collection package_data. So you can go for loop in it.
Here is the schema of your json data.
[image: schema of your json string]

```
foreach(dynamic item in jsonObj.item.package_data)
{
     //item.tracking_no;
     //item.package_reference
}
```

Comment: it is working, but you should change `jsonObj.item.package_data` to `jsonObj.data.package_data`

Answer (score 2):

You can create Types for your JSON:

```
namespace Example
{
    using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    public class MyObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public Data Data { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("success")]
        public bool Success { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("order_reference")]
        public string OrderReference { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("package_data")]
        public PackageDatum[] PackageData { get; set; }
    }

    public class PackageDatum
    {
        [JsonProperty("package_reference")]
        public string PackageReference { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("tracking_no")]
        public string TrackingNo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

then you can deserialize using `JsonConvert.Deserialize<MyObject>(input);`